# Not able to include image in html using relative path

Tags: html, image, liferay

i have a porlet running in liferay portal.after successfully entering the details , i want to download the details in an html page , in which i have to include an image.

this is done by giving the absolute path as:

```
<img src="http://localhost:8080/Demo-portlet/images/logo-1.jpg"
```

and it works fine.

My portlet structure is :

Demo-portlet-->docroot-->images-->logo-1.jpg

Now i want to do this by using relative path. i tried as below but it didnt work out:

```
  <img src="../Demo-portlet/docroot/images/logo-1.jpg" />
  <img src="./docroot/images/logo-1.jpg" />
  <img src="./images/logo-1.jpg" />
```

None of the above worked. please tell me how this can be done.

Adding the html path:

Demo-portlet-->docroot-->download.html

Comment: Where in that portlet structure is your html located? Directly in the folder docroot?

Comment: @lupz yes inside the docroot folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<img src="images/logo-1.jpg" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Your portlet can be embedded on random pages. It's the page's URL that you need to be relative to, not the portlet.

If you have your portlet on `http://localhost:8080/web/guest/home` or `http://localhost:8080/web/guest/about-us/contact/addresses`, the relative address would need to be different. Thus I'd recommend to be relative with regards to the server name, but not with regard to the embedding URL: At development time you have no clue what name the pages that embed your portlet will have.

Go with `<img src="/Demo-portlet/images/logo-1.jpg" />` or look up the servlet context (e.g. replace "/Demo-Portlet" with a dynamic value, so that you don't have to hard-code it).

*(sorry, IDE not running and I'm always mixing up if it's `request.getServletContext()` or something else - try for yourself and comment here, I'll edit this answer when you give the full code). The dynamic stuff - on a jsp - would be `<img src="<%=request.getServletContext()%>/images/logo-1.jpg" />`*

Comment: thats right but the problem is i am working in html so cant access servletcontext. and < img="/Demo-portlet/images/logo-1.jpg"/> didnt work out

Comment: what are you getting? 404? Try monitoring the requests, e.g. with Firebug or equivalent tools. See what actually gets sent back and forth. Technically you should be able to just strip protocol and servername/port from the URL that you give in the question. Don't forget the leading slash "/"